# Selenium problem when I press onclick() on a box

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python with Selenium to scrape: https://www.vivastreet.cl/arrendar-habitacion/santiago-comuna/pieza-con-ba-o-privado---260-000-plaza-de-armas--/203600147  I need to take different parameters, but I have a problem taking the phone ("Ver Telefono" in Spanish).

I clicked in the web box with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary vs-contact-btn phone_link_right phone_link_desktop']").click()
```

This shows me the telephone, but my problem is that after this it appears an alert (I think it's an alert):

[image: Alert Problem]

After this, I can't do anything.

I have a solution but I didn't like it (quit driver and open it again, too slow and horrible code):

```
driver.quit()  
driver=webdriver.Chrome("/Users/nicolasaguirre/Desktop/HouseFlats/webScraping/chromedriver")
```

Comment: Have you tried to switch to the alert and perform any action?

Comment: Have you looked into the web inspector to see if the phone number is a property of the web object?

Comment: @KILLtheWEEZELi dit it and didnt work

Comment: @Abhinav i tried with selenium alert but didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telephone is accessible within this element:

```html
<span class="phone_link" id="phone-button-dt" data-phone-number="56945117562"> &nbsp;Ver Teléfono&nbsp; </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary vs-contact-btn phone_link_right phone_link_desktop']").click()` behaves differently in different browser or platform. In mobile it copies number to dialer. In desktop it depends on software that you have installed.If clicked using Firefox it shows the following.
[image]

In chrome if you have phone linked it shows the following.
[image]

So basically it behaves differently in differently in different platform. If you really want to test you need to make definite test environment and test.

Comment: Yes :). Im using chrome (maybe i need try with another browser, i havent). The code i put it shows that im using chrome. Thx, gonna try this!!